# prevent DIV tag from scrolling inside another DIV and show full content

Tags: html, css

i have 3 divs inside a div but the last div is scrolling between the 2nd div and end of page. I want to make that div show the full content instead of scrolling inside the div. How can i make that happen.?
I deleted my entire css and it is still the same.

Edit: I found that one of the parent div's height is getting set to 599px automatically. without any code being given in the css. how can i prevent this from happening

Comment: can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: Please check if you get a solution from this: http://jsfiddle.net/XNwbt/458/

Comment: @RocketSurgeon... i want to prevent div from scrolling. not make it scrolling inside body..

Comment: Does the parent div have a fixed height?

Comment: Check your positioning of parent divs and child divs

Comment: I found that one of the parent div's height is getting set to 599px automatically. without any code being given in the css. how can i prevent this from happening

Comment: Can you post a link to your site?  Or at least all the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

If none of your divs have a fixed height, they should all expand to display their content without scrolling.  In the following code, you can add as many `<p>` tags as you wish.

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  padding:10px;
}
#one {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #282828;
}
#two {
  background: #888888;
  color: #282828;
}
#three {
  background: #282828;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="one">
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
    <p>data</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: none  of my div's have a fixed height. but a fixed height is being set when loaded in browser.

Comment: you'll need to post some code so we can see where the fixed height comes from.  Check in `html` and `body` CSS.